# Where can I find VHDL libraries? Is there a library for a PLL?

Tags: vhdl, pll, library

I heard in the following link that a V4 library about this topic exists, but I'm not able to find it anywere and to understand how to use it:

[Look at the last reply at this link](http://www.edaboard.com/thread184005.html)

Comment: PLL is not a digital circuit, you can't design it using digital logic.

Comment: There are digital PLLs - try Google.

Comment: The poster in the link is talking about instantiating a PLL primitive in the FPGA. Look at the documentation for whatever FPGA you are using, and find out if it has any dedicated PLL-like functionality. If it has this, it will have documentation and an instantiation template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuous-time PLL (phase-locked loop) is an analog circuit and cannot be described in a purely digital hardware description language such as VHDL.

However, it is possible to construct a discrete-time approximation to a PLL by using an NCO (numerically-controlled oscillator, AKA "DDS", or direct digital synthesizer) as the oscillator block in a PLL. You also need a discrete-time implementation of a phase/frequency comparator.

I have done this on several projects with a great deal of success. However, the details of the design tend to be very application-specific, and I doubt that you'll find a complete, turn-key implementation in any library.

Comment: I have found the library UNISIM. In the following link, there is the component DCM_BASE, which seems to have PLL.
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/virtex4_scm.pdf
It has CLKIN as clock input and CLKFB as clock reference. It has many output, among them it has LOCKED and CLK0. When LOCKED is 1, it means that the PLL is in phase with CLKIN. But you can also usa CLKFX, by modifing CLKFX_MULTIPLY and CLKFX_DIVIDE.
The problem is that I have no idea how to install UNISIM...I'm using MODELSIM

Comment: The unisim library provides simulation models for the primitives found in FPGAs (Xilinx FPGAs, in this case). The Digital Clock Manager (DCM) module contains a hardware PLL (analog, continuous time), among other things. It is found in Xilinx FPGAs. It is not a synthesizable description of a PLL, but rather, it is just a simulatable model (approximation) for the hardware primitive.